# Iphone Application Porting to Blackberry RIM

Tags: java, android, ios4, porting, blackberry-jde

I have developed  an application for iPhone. Is there any way to port that application on to Blackberry RIM so that i can avoid rewriting the application in Java for Blackberry RIM?

I am rewriting my application for black berry,**suggest me the way to rewrite** so that later stage **I can port that directly to Android**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2.What about memory related stuff? i mean in UI perspective and the way memory is handled in iphone compared to blackberry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The closest thing I am aware of is projects like PhoneGap (and others, including Appcelerator Titanium) which allow for cross platform development for smart phones including iPhone, Android, and Blackberry by creating hardware specific wrappers around WebApps.  PhoneGap essentially allows for Web Apps to have more complete access to the hardware and operating system of these devices (like the camera, motion detection, push notification, etc.) by wrapping the Web App in a customized browser that provides javascript handles for accessing the hardware.

PhoneGap will even build binaries for each of the supported platforms on their servers (with limitations...for example, if you want to submit to the Apple App Store, you currently need to build the iPhone binary yourself due to developer certificate issues).

So if your app could be (re)conceived as a Web App with some extra help accessing device specific hardward features, then PhoneGap or similar development kits might provide some shortcuts to cross platform deployment.

Comment: If i have to start from the scratch can you suggest me some links how to start with?

Comment: http://www.phonegap.com/start, http://www.phonegap.com/about, and http://build.phonegap.com

Answer (score 0):

not really.  If your app is written in custom objective-c code, then you will need to manually port it to blackberry java.  there are some cross-platform app frameworks out there though that may allow you to do what you need, but youd have to redevelop your app with those frameworks.

Comment: yes my application is written in objective c using cocoa frameworks and other provided by apple.Do i have to replace the frameworks my blackberry related frameworks and rewrite the application? or is it better to start from the scratch?

Comment: the BB classes and cocoa touch are radically different, it's not just a matter of renaming functions and classes and changing the syntax from obj-c to java.  youll have to recreate the app from scratch on blackberry.